# i want to get difference of days by subtracting dates in java using Gregorian calendar:

Tags: java

```
GregorianCalendar last = new GregorianCalendar(py,pm-1,pd);
System.out.println(last.getTime());
GregorianCalendar present = new GregorianCalendar(py,pm-1,pd);
System.out.println(present.getTime());

long diff = Math.abs(prsent.getTime() - last.getTime());
```

Problem facing when subtracting these two dates

Comment: _Problem facing when..._ What problem?

Answer (score 0):

ChronoUnit is what you can use for the difference between dates:

```
long minutesDiff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(present.toInstant(), last.toInstant());
```